# How to make context manager in Rust

Tags: rust

I want to make a context manager with python-like usage.

I have a socket, which I will read from and write to.
and then, a device struct, which hold the socket, to command the device through the socket

```
pub struct MyDevice{
    socket: MySocket,
    /* ... */
}
impl MyDevice{
    pub fn new()->MyDevice { todo!() }
    pub fn command(&mut self, s:&str)->std::io::Result<String>{ 
        self.socket.write(s)?; 
        self.socket.read()
    }
    /* ... */
}
```

a normal operation would look something like this

```
let mut device = MyDevice::new();

device.command("Push setting A")?;
device.command("Perform task 1")?;
device.command("Pop setting A")?;
    
device.command("Perform task 2")?;

device.command("Push setting A")?;
device.command("Perform task 3")?;
device.command("Pop setting A")?; //<-- notice how setting A is load and unload multiple times
```

how could I create a context manager like in python

```
    some pseudo code of what I wanted

    let setting_a : ContextManager = ContextManager::new(
        enter : ||{
            device.command("Push setting A");
        },
        exit: || {
            device.command("Pop setting A");
        }
    )

    with setting_a {
        device.command("Perform task 1");
    }

    device.command("Perform task 2");

    with setting_a {
        device.command("Perform task 3");
    }
    
    with setting_a{
        device.command("Perform task 4");
        with setting_b{
            device.command("Perform task 5");
        }
        device.command("Perform task 6");
    }
```

this was my attempt, and it kinda works with some rc/refcell magic, but it does not account for context that need to perform some task.

```
impl MyDevice{
    /* ... */
    pub fn with_param<F,O>(&mut self, param:Param,f:F)->O
    where
        F: Fn()->O
    {
        let last_param:Param = self.param.clone();
        self.set_param(param);
        let o = f();
        self.set_param(last_param);
        o
    }
}

device.with_param(param, ||{/* ... */})

// v ----------- psuedo code  ------------------------------ v
let setting_a : ContextManager = ContextManager::new(
        enter : ||{
            device.command("Push setting A");
            device.command("Perform some task a-1");
        },
        exit: || {
            device.command("Pop setting A");
            device.command("Perform some task a-2");
        }
    )
// this doesn't not work on the with_param function, 
// since it not only have to set param, 
// but also need to perform some sub-task to enter and exit the context.
```

**1.** what would be a sanest way to organize this kind of code? good ol'`Rc<refCell<_>>`? `macro`?

**2.** I want it to be `panic`-proof, I know using `refCell` might cause panic, can I avoid using `refCell` in this case?

**3.** what if I will need to pass this between thread in the future? and how to async-proof it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Cafce25's suggestion of a high-level function is a fine option and is used in some places in rust (e.g. scoped threads), but the reason context managers don't exist and are not necessary is mostly that they're an inferior sibling of [RAII guards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization), which is what Rust favors and which you can see in:

- [file objects](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.File.html)
- [locks](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.MutexGuard.html)
- [automated reference counting](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Rc.html)
- ...

In that context, you could have a `settings` method (or a method for each setting) which would push the setting on call, returning a `SettingsGuard` which would pop the same setting on drop.

To make borrows work, and for safety and clarity, you would probably want the `SettingsGuard` to have an exclusive (/ unique / mut) reference to the device, and to allow performing commands (and maybe nested settings) through itself, yielding something like:

```
dev.command("thing");

{    
    let mut g = dev.setting("g");
    g.command("foo");
    
    let mut stacked = g.setting("x");
    stacked.command("bar");
    drop(stacked);
    
    g.command("x");
}
dev.command("bob");
```

This way as long as a setting is pushed, the device is interacted with through that setting's guard, such that it's easier to name (and justify naming), and the execution context is clearer (the compiler will prevent sending command through a parent context as long as the setting guard lives).

As you can see in the example, a setting would be "popped" by either dropping the corresponding guard explicitely (with something like `drop(g);`), or the end of its block (using anonymous blocks in that manner is relatively normal).

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion the sanest way would be to *not* take `device` as part of the closure, but instead pass it as a parameter:

```rust
#[derive(Clone, Copy)]
struct ContextManager<O, C> {
    open: O,
    close: C,
}

let ctx = ContextManager {
    open: |device: &mut MyDevice| device.command("Push setting A"),
    close: |device: &mut MyDevice| device.command("Pop setting A"),
};
```

You can implement the `with` as function on `MyDevice` which gives the nicer API:

```rust
impl MyDevice {
    fn with<F, R, O, C, E>(&mut self, ctx: ContextManager<O, C>, f: F) -> Result<R, E>
    where
        F: FnOnce(&mut Self) -> Result<R, E>,
        O: FnOnce(&mut Self) -> Result<(), E>,
        C: FnOnce(&mut Self) -> Result<(), E>,
    {
        (ctx.open)(self)?;
        let ret = f(self)?;
        (ctx.close)(self)?;
        Ok(ret)
    }
}
fn main() {
    let ctx = ContextManager {
        open: |device: &mut MyDevice| device.command("Push setting A"),
        close: |device: &mut MyDevice| device.command("Pop setting A"),
    };

    device.with(ctx, |device| device.command("Perform task 1"))?;
    device.command("Perform task 2")?;
    device.with(ctx, |device| device.command("Perform task 3"))?;
    Ok(())
}
```

but if you do not want to change the API of `MyDevice` it's easily implemented on `ContextManager` instead.

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1e2407a7766c36f131d4cc74a331738c)

3. isn't as easy to accomplish because we can't write code that is conditionally asynchronous yet. But you can easily adapt this pattern to an `async` version as well.