# How do I convert Python context manager to Rust?

Tags: rust, contextmanager, raii

I have this Python code from an existing project that I'm trying to port to Rust as a learning exercise (plus a thing I actually have a use for if I succeed):

```py
class BaseKlazz:
    # stuff

    # from contextlib import contextmanager
    @contextmanager
    def set_directory(self, path: str):
        orig_dir = os.getcwd()
        try:
            os.chdir(path)
            yield
        finally:
            os.chdir(org_dir)
```

```py
class Klazz(BaseKlazz):
    # stuff

    def funktion():
        # do stuff
        try:
            # rm -rf somedir
            # mkdir -p somedir

            with self.set_directory(somedir): # <-- How do I port this to Rust?
                # do things, maybe write files, maybe more mkdir, maybe write more files
                pass

            # potentially do more things with original dir
        except:
            # handle/propagate library/application errors
            pass
```

The original codebase is in Python and therefore makes use of OOP and exceptions, which are not the easiest things to port to Rust, but manageable.

The generators / context managers it uses though, I'm not sure how I can port to rust. I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77041687) which suggests I use RAII, but I'm still unsure how to make that work:

```rs
pub struct ChdirGuard {
    original_path: PathBuf
}

impl ChdirGuard {
    pub fn new(target_path: PathBuf) -> ChdirGuard {
        let chdir_guard = ChdirGuard {
            original_path: std::env::current_dir().unwrap()
        };

        std::env::set_current_dir(&target_path);

        return chdir_guard
    }
}

impl Drop for ChdirGuard {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        std::env::set_current_dir(&self.original_path)
    }
}
```

```rs
struct Klazz {}
impl Klazz {
    pub fn funktion(&self) {
        // rm -rf somedir + check result of rm, because rust
        // mkdir -p somedir + check result of mkdir, because rust

        {
            let _ = ChdirGuard::new(PathBuf::from("somedir"));

            // do things, maybe write files, maybe more mkdir, maybe write more files
        }

        // potentially do more things with original dir
    }
}
```

Looks a bit jank, certainly not used to seeing a random unnamed block in the middle of a function. Maybe I'm missing something, or is this really the way to do RAII in Rust? Will it work if I `.unwrap()` and explode, return prematurely from `funktion` with a `Result`, etc. ?

Comment: `let _ = …` will not work as it'll [immediately drop the `ChdirGuard`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/nightly-rustc/rustc_lint/let_underscore/static.LET_UNDERSCORE_DROP.html)

Comment: `with` in python is very much like introducing a block. Alternatively, you can name the guard and `drop(guard)`.

Comment: And yes, it will execute the `Drop` code in any case, if you panic (e.g. `unwrap()`) - assuming panics unwind and not abort, if you `return`, return via `?`, etc..

Comment: In this case `ChdirGuard` does look strange, but usually the guard object has other useful properties in addition to `Drop`. For example, `MutexGuard` gives you access to the data protected by the (now locked) mutex (and unlocks it on `Drop`). A `File` gives you access to the file's contents (and closes the file on `Drop`). Once you get more used to Rust, you'll blend in RAII naturally rather than try to map Python's idioms 1-to-1.